# Fibonacci C++ - invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’ and initializing argument 2/3 of ‘int fibo(int, int*, int*)’

Tags: c++, int, fibonacci

Hello i have problems with this program in C++ on Fibonacci, i tried to search on google the errors, but i didn't find a solution/explanation.

There is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int fibo(int,int*,int*);
int conta=0;

int main() {
    int n,m,f;
    int fibN=1;
    int fibNMeno1=0;
    cout << "Calcolo del numero di Fibonacci di indice n \n \n" << endl;
    cout << "Introdurre n (positivo e minore di 47:" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    n=abs(n/1);

    if (n<1) {
        fibN=0;
    }
    else {
        fibo(n,fibN,fibNMeno1);
    }

    cout << "\n Fibonacci di indice " << n << "vale: " << fibN << endl;
    cout << "\n numero di chiamate ricorsive: " << conta << "\n\n" << endl;
}

int fibo(int n, int*pfn, int* pfnMeno1) {
    int t;
    int tFn,tFnMeno1,tF;
    conta++;
    if (n==1) {
        *pfn=1; *pfnMeno1=0; return 1;
    }
    else {
        t=n%2; n=n/2;
        fibo(n,pfn,pfnMeno1);
        tFn=(*pfn)*(*pfn)+2*(*pfn)*(*pfnMeno1);
        tFnMeno1=(*pfn)*(*pfn) + (*pfnMeno1)*(*pfnMeno1);
        if(t) {
            tF=tFn;
            tFn=tFn + tFnMeno1;
            tFnMeno1=tF;
        }
        *pfn=tFn;
        *pfnMeno1=tFnMeno1;
        return 3;
    }

}
```

Where is the error? How it work on c++ with *?

```
fibonacci.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
    fibonacci.cpp:23:22: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
     fibo(n,fibN,fibNMeno1);
                          ^
    fibonacci.cpp:7:5: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘int fibo(int, int*, int*)’
     int fibo(int,int*,int*);
         ^
    fibonacci.cpp:23:22: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
     fibo(n,fibN,fibNMeno1);
                          ^
    fibonacci.cpp:7:5: note:   initializing argument 3 of ‘int fibo(int, int*, int*)’
     int fibo(int,int*,int*);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fibN/fibNMeno1 has int type, but your function req. int * type, which is a pointer to an int.

If you want pass an int as int * you need to take an adress (& symbol) of your local variable, like this:

```
fibo(n,&fibN,&fibNMeno1);
```

Answer (score 0):

because you might want to  `fibo(n,&fibN,&fibNMeno1)` instead of `fibo(n,fibN,fibNMeno1)`...

Your `fibo` function takes an `int` and two pointers. you were calling with three ints. therefore the compiler fails to make an implicit conversion.